# Why is total pressure also called stagnation pressure when it is not measured at stagnation points?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Total pressure is the sum of static pressure $P$ (pressure the fluid would have if being at rest) and dynamic pressure $\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2$ (due to velocity effects).

On the other hand, a stagnation point is one where the fluid is at rest. Logically, the total pressure is then equal to the static pressure.

However, the total pressure is also called the stagnation pressure, yet it can be measured anywhere, not just at stagnation points. Why do we then also refer to total pressure as stagnation pressure, as in [this article](https://www.simscale.com/blog/what-is-static-pressure/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Total", "dynamic" and "static" pressure comes from experimental nomenclature, and are the **local quantities** defined as:

- static pressure is pressure indeed, the thermodynamic variable we all call as "pressure", $p(\mathbf{r}, t)$
- dynamic pressure is defined as $q_d(\mathbf{r},t) := \frac{1}{2} \rho(\mathbf{r}, t) |\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r}, t)|^2$,
- for **incompressible flows** total pressure is the sum of the static and dynamic pressure, $p^{tot}(\mathbf{r},t) = p(\mathbf{r},t) + q_d(\mathbf{r},t)$.

This definition is useful in flows where Bernoulli's theorem holds. As an example, in steady incompressible irrotational flows, with constant density and negligible effects of viscosity and volume forces, Bernoulli's theorem states that the quantity $p^{tot}(\mathbf{r},t) =  p(\mathbf{r},t) + \frac{1}{2}\rho |\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r},t)|^2 = \overline{p}^{tot} $, that we called total pressure, is uniform in the flow.

Now, let's focus on your question. The following sentence

> The total pressure is then equal to the static pressure

is false. If the assumptions of Bernoulli's theorem are satisfied, the right sentence reads "total pressure is equal to (static) pressure **at stagnation points**", i.e. where $\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r}) = \mathbf{0}$,

$\overline{p}^{tot} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\rho|\mathbf{v}|^2}_{=0} + p$

and that's the reason why you can talk about total pressure as the stagnation pressure.

Comment: Why do you restrict the definition of total pressure to incompressible flows? Total pressure occurs in the conservation of energy (power balance) equation in the Navier Stokes equations and that equation is valid for compressible flows. Moreover, at stagnation points static and total pressure are always equal (by definition: Velocity is zero). In inviscid, incompressible flow the (static) pressure at a stagnation point is equal to the *upstream* total pressure, i.e. one can compare pressures at different positions.

Comment: Because for compressible flows you need to take into account the internal energy as well. Derive Bernoulli's theorem for compressible flows from total energy balance, and you will easily realize that the total pressure defined for incompressible flows is not the same as  the total pressure needed in compressible flows.

Comment: I just looked it up in the Ansys CFX Theory Manual and you are right. I always thought total pressure was just defined as p + rho/2*v^2 and I often asked myself why people claimed it was "the pressure that results from an isentropic deceleration to zero velocity", when clearly the density increases in such a change of state.

Comment: Yes. That's the point. And please, remember the word isentropic, since when shocks occur (whatever you model), isentropy doesn't hold: in the inviscid model, you model through discontinuities, so that you can't even use differential equations, but you need jump conditions

Answer (score 1):

Stagnation pressure (total pressure) is the pressure measured when the fluid is brought to stagnation isentropically (i.e. without losses).  In that case any dynamic pressure (kinetic energy) is converted fully into static pressure (potential energy) where it can be measured.

Find a description of a Pitot Tube to see an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

The article mentions something that can be true, but total pressure and stagnation pressure are not strict synonyms.

Total pressure is indeed defined as the sum of the static pressure and the dynamic pressure. On the other hand, stagnation pressure is defined as the static pressure at a stagnation point.

Here's an example to illustrate when the two are equal: in a pitot tube. A pitot tube is a tube mounted outside an aircraft, pointing toward the nose of the aircraft. Inside the pitot tube, there is a stagnation point, since air has nowhere else to go. Thus, we measure stagnation pressure inside the pitot tube (in fact, we measure pitot pressure, which is equal to stagnation pressure only for subsonic flows).

Way in front of the pitot tube, in freestream conditions, we have the total pressure. Assuming an incompressible flow, when entering the pitot tube, the dynamic pressure gets converted into static pressure, so we can measure the freestream total pressure by equating it to the stagnation pressure.